# Git Bash won't let me ls or cd

Tags: bash, git, ls, cd

I've been using Git Bash for a while now and it usually works perfectly fine. However, it stopped working today and won't let me ls or cd. When I try to ls it gives me the error "An unknown error occured." When I try to cd it gives me the error "Error changing directories."  I think git might be working but can't test it because I can't navigate to a folder. I did try LS (in caps) and that worked, but the files in the directory were all white instead of the normal different colors. CD (in caps) does not work. pwd works, and returns that I am in directory /.

I googled for this but can't find anybody with the same errors, which is pretty hilarious. I tried reinstalling git bash several times but the errors never get fixed. Anyone have any ideas?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does typing `dir` work? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Without knowing more it looks like you messed up the PATH variable directory pointing to where `ls` and other missing executables live.

Comment: dir works, it gives me the same thing as LS (caps). Here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/02K2xlp.png

Comment: David: That's what I thought as well. Here is a screenshot of my PATH system environment variable, it would be great if you could tell me if anything looks out of place. https://i.imgur.com/iDDC5Ma.png

The last part of this variable, C:\Program Files\Git\cmd, is the same as on my laptop, where Git Bash did not stop working. I haven't edited my system environment variables on this computer between the time Git Bash was working and stopped working, so I am hesitant to say this is the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, I figured it out. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me out. My roommate went into my computer when I wasn't looking and aliased the cd and ls commands to errors he made up as a prank. There goes 2 hours...

Comment: In that case, it would be better to delete the question. And change your password

Comment: My password is fine, I left my computer logged in because I assumed that he would not do anything to it.

Comment: And I'll leave the question up, at least temporarily, just in case the people who tried to help me out above want to know what the "error" was.

Comment: BTW I was about to suggest trying `command ls` and `command cd` just to dodge a possibility of an alias or a shell function. It should have worked for you.

Comment: Aha! Always watch out for a <s>rigged demo</s> prank. :-)